# Segfaulting only without valgrind

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I get my final "done" message with valgrind, and get this exit report:

```
==3434== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3434==     in use at exit: 8,432 bytes in 4 blocks
==3434==   total heap usage: 4,369 allocs, 8,037 frees, 377,356 bytes allocated
==3434== 
==3434== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3434==    definitely lost: 152 bytes in 1 blocks
==3434==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3434==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3434==    still reachable: 8,192 bytes in 2 blocks
==3434==         suppressed: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
==3434== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3434== 
==3434== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3434== ERROR SUMMARY: 100190 errors from 140 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But when I run it without valgrind, it segfaults immediately. Does valgrind suppress a certain kind of error that I should be looking for? I can't find any information about this online

Comment: Any "invalid read" or "invalid write" in the valgrind output?

Comment: tons of them. Those must be bad.

Comment: Yep. They mean you're reading or writing memory that's not yours. Gotta fix 'em all.

Comment: I agree with @DanielFischer.  Fix all the warnings first, and it's likely that will eliminate the seg-fault as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valgrind runs the program in a different environment than if you run it from the shell.
This can prevent some crashes when relative to memory exhaustion or array outbounding.

Correct your 140 contexts of errors and you'll be okay.

Answer (score 3):

Memcheck does not perform complete bounds check and because it has it's own memory allocator it might suppress faults that you otherwise would get. Use a debugger instead.

Answer (score 2):

One example of an error which sometimes is not caught by Valgrind is when you free memory and then reference it through another pointer which was also pointing at the same place.

I'm not sure why this happens. Perhaps the Valgrind environment handles memory allocation and deallocation differently. [As Eregrith says]

A quick way to check this would be to temporarily comment your free() function calls and see if it still segfaults. [Uncomment them later, once you fix them!]